# How do xml file and java file interact each other in android?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I'm learning android about a month. As I study onClickListner and xml's onClick attribute, I got a question.
After I write the code `android:onClick="showMap"` on xml and "public void showMap(View view)" on java file, the application make a button which can be perform the showMap method.
I could understand the `onClickListner` control the xml element by id(`R.id.somthing`).

How can the showMap method notice the method act as the attribute of the very xml element? I found some other question and it said it can be because of the view parameter, but I'm not convinced perfectly. How do xml and java file interact each other? Please let me know their internal interaction or which the source code do I have to see to understand my question.

Thank you.

p.s When I asked to my friend who is good at android, he answered me to find "xml parsing algorithm". But I couldn't find satisfying result.

Answer (score 0):

The `xml` is parsed a compile time and the corresponding View's object is created, with the attributes you specified. The method you declare in the View's onClick property is managed through reflection. You can take a look to it [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/view/View.java#2003)

Comment: Now I'm looking at the link here. That's what I wanted to find. Thank you for your help. I'm gonna master the android!

Answer (score 0):

The xml files bundled with our app (converted to binary xml for performance reasons by aapt/2), and are then inflated at runtime by using the LayoutInflater.